# Anylogic - agent location triggered by condition

Tags: location, conditional-statements, simulation, agent, anylogic

I have an issue concerning the agent location in one of my Anylogic simulations. I want to set a condition that defines which path an agent will take in the visualization of my simulation.

In a delay block in the main agent I wrote

```
if(agent.previousStation==1){
    path01;
    }
else {
    path21;
    }
```

into the agent location field.

When building the model anylogic presents me with these errors:

> Description: Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete
> LocalVariableDeclaration. Location: FVMMerkmale/shopfloor/wegzeit1 -
> Delay

and

> Description: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s).
> Location: FVMMerkmale/shopfloor - Agent Type

writing "return" in front of the path does not help either and gives different errors:

> Description: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s).
> Location: FVMMerkmale/shopfloor - Agent Type
>
> Description: path21 cannot be resolved to a variable. Location:
> FVMMerkmale/shopfloor/wegzeit1 - Delay
>
> Description: Void methods cannot return a value. Location:
> FVMMerkmale/shopfloor/wegzeit1 - Delay
>
> Description: agent cannot be resolved to a variable. Location:
> FVMMerkmale/shopfloor/wegzeit1 - Delay

The path-elements are in the main agent. Using the value editor to choose the correct path will work.

According to the anylogic help, it is possible to bind the agent location to a condition:

> Otherwise, if you want to set different nodes for agents here, you can
> write a Java expression that will return different nodes depending on
> some conditions.
> https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fagentbased%2FContinuous_Layouts.html

How do I write a condition that defines a path or node as the agent location?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code, which is the compressed version of the if statement using ? and : operators (without using semicollon)

```
agent.previousStation==1 ? path01 : path21
```

More info about these operators here:
http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html